# IOS UITabBar colors

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

i'm experimenting with tab bars and im going crazy trying to set the color of the icons as i like...

i read the docs and i found how to change the color of the icon when it's selected. but how to change the grayish color that the icons have when the app is loaded??

```
 UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
 //UITabBar.appearance().selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

also... what's the difference between the two? selectedImageTintColor is just deprecated in favor of tintColor ?

i read about methods like unselected

Comment: iOS will always use a shading of your tintColor for the unselected tabs. If you wish to have a more custom UI, I would largely recommend not relying on standard controls, but write a custom control instead.

Comment: a shade would be fine, but that's totally grey...